# Filter numeric field

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$201").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=10"*
```

When I click on the filter and type in the search bar `10*` I get all results that start with `10`. When using the macro, that doesn't work. The goal is for the macro to filter using the first two numbers provided by me.

Can you assist?

Comment: I tried this,but instead of performing the ,,begins with search'' it automatically selects the entire number for example I searched "10*" and the script recording ,recoreded : ,,Criteria1:="10439" ; Criteria2:="10943" etc.

Comment: "01* was a typo,I'm writing the code on another pc,with no Internet Connection. I used the code below writen by Gary's Student.The thing is that my numbers are zip code formated , not text.

Comment: Germany Zip codes : ,,10965" ,,25541" ,,10965" ,,01127" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the problem seems to have been trying to apply a text filter to a numeric field.
Instead of:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$201").AutoFilter Field:=5 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$201").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=10"*
```

just:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$201").AutoFilter Field:=5, _  
    Criteria1:=">=10000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=10999"
```

seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

The following will work **only if the values are text**:

```
Sub Macro2()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$201").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=10*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

If the values are not text, then use a "helper" column.

**EDIT#1**:

For postal codes in column E, this will filter out (hide) rows not containing "10*" codes:

```
Sub GoingPostal()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("E2:E201")
        st = Left(r.Text, 2)
        If st <> "10" Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi pnuts:  Sometimes **AutoFilter** gets confused on numbers/text..............your suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Hi,the values are zip code format.I think this is the reason why it's not working.What do you mean by helper column? thanks!