# Search through the column by integer retrieves no values

Tags: excel, vba, format, cells

I have made 3 of these search boxes which retrieves value(s) when I search. Only when I am using text the values are retrieved. Whenever I use numbers, the column retrieves no values. The best way would be that the textbox could search both with text and integer.

I think it must have something to do with the format, I have changed the format for the column by "selecting the column, right-click on the column, select format cells, change to text". But this did not work..

This is how it looks before I search by number. 
[image]

This is how it looks when I type in number(s). 
[image]

Here is the VBA code I have been using, as mentioned it works when I search by text but not numbers..

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
        Sheet1.Range("A2:CM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox3.Value & "*"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter numeric field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375818/filter-numeric-field)

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria is a text filter; it will not detect numbers in your data, unless the numbers are entered as text.  Changing the `numberformat` of the cell will not change values which were entered as numbers to text.  They need to be reentered as text.  This can be done programmatically; by prefixing the number with the single quote, or by formatting the column as text before entering the numeric values.

You could also run the filter twice -- first with a text filter, then with a numeric filter.

Or, as pointed out by @Ralph in comments below, you could also use a helper column using the `TEXT` function to convert the numeric data to text, and then filter on that column.

Best way to do this may depend on your ultimate goal.

Comment: While I'd strongly recommend *not* to convert numbers (especially in an Excel file) to text you are (unfortunately) correct. Personally, I'd rather advise to use any of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20376386/1153513

Comment: @Ralph Yes, a helper column would work also. But, as I wrote, the **best way** of accomplishing the task depends on unsupplied information.  I will add your suggestion to my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Rather include the 7 lines of VBA code. If the OP includes those into his existing VBA code (rather then using AutoFilter) then the case is closed and solved.

Comment: @Ralph  Again, not enough information.  For example, that code might be OK with a small DB, and excruciatingly slow with a large DB.

Answer (score 0):

with that "numbers" kind as shown in  OP's screenshot, a possible solution would be the following:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    Dim criteria As String
    With TextBox3
        If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
            criteria = .Value
        Else
            criteria = "*" & .Value & "*"
        End If
    End With
    Sheet1.Range("A2:CM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=criteria
End Sub
```

Comment: @DlerAri have you gone through it?

Comment: @DlerAri it'd be nice from to give feedbacks to people trying helping you